# Getting specific user data in ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

So im trying to get a list of data recorded in the database for that specific user who's logged in. This should be an easy task, but I cant get it to work.

Here's what I tried and I get the following errors:

"The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties."

Here's some code:

Model:

```
public partial class TimesheetEntry
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

        public decimal HoursWorked { get; set; }

        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Aviato.Models.TimesheetEntry>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Project.ProjectName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EntryDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HoursWorked)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project.ProjectName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EntryDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoursWorked)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "User")
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class TimesheetEntryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AviatoModel _db = new AviatoModel();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var userId = (int)Session["userId"]; // I have made a breakpoint and confirm that the user get it's unique Id.
            var user = _db.Users.Find(userId);
            var timesheetentries = _db.TimesheetEntries.Include(t => t.Project).Include(t => t.User == user);

            return View(timesheetentries.ToList());
        }
```

It's easy to get all the records in the database just by deleting the first two rows of code in the controller, but that's not my goal here.

Please help!

Comment: Do not change up your question completely, especially after an answer has already been posted. That's not good form. Instead, ask a new question.

Comment: the issue is `Include(t => t.User == user)`. This is not a valid expression for `Include`. You most likely want `Where` here, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple, don't overly complicate it. Just filter the entries by the user id.

```
var userId = (int)Session["userId"];
return View(timesheetentries.Where(t => t.UserId == userId).ToList());
```